# IOError: [Errno url error] invalid proxy for http: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

Tags: python, windows, proxy

I'm having some trouble with my script.
It's supposed to open a website trough a proxy but I get, always, this error, with several proxies that I'm trying to...

What could it be?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shady\Desktop\ptzplace.3.0 - Copy.py", line 43, in <module>
    h = urllib.urlopen(website, proxies = {'http': proxy})
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 200, in open
    return self.open_unknown_proxy(proxy, fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 219, in open_unknown_proxy
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'invalid proxy for %s' % type, proxy)
IOError: [Errno url error] invalid proxy for http: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

The script is this

```
proxylist = ['79.174.195.84:80',
             '79.174.195.82:80',
             '80.233.184.227:8080',
             '79.174.195.80:80',
             '80.233.184.226:8080',
             '79.174.33.95:3128']
for proxy in proxylist:
            h = urllib.urlopen(website, proxies = {'http': proxy})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try the next code with your proxylist but it tooks so long, so I got other proxies :P

```
import urllib
website = 'http://www.google.com/'
proxylist = ('http://75.101.215.123:9090', 'http://94.198.47.6:3128')
connlist = (urllib.urlopen(website, proxies = {'http': proxy}) for proxy in proxylist)
for conn in connlist:
    print conn.read()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: hmmm... apparently, your works... I will try modificate mine using your as base...

Comment: very strange... your code in my script don't work either... what a hell

Answer (score 9):

Try `urllib2.urlopen` instead of `urllib.urlopen`. I've had situations where `urllib.urlopen` chokes on my proxy server but `urllib2.urlopen` opens it fine.

Comment: Ooh.. this one worked for me but I don't have any idea why. Like the rest of my life :D

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need the http schema identifier before each proxy:

```
proxylist = ['http://79.174.195.84:80',... 'http://79.174.33.95:3128']
```